# ¿Como agrupar datos de una tabla relacionada en Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Quiero agrupar los registros que tienen más de un registro relacionado.
Ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla llamada asignaciones y otra tabla llamada ventas, entonces una asignación puede tener muchas ventas. En la tabla asignaciones tengo 2 registros y en ventas tengo 3,

```
ventas                            asignaciones
id | asignacion_id                id | user_id
---|---------------               ---|---------
1  | 1                            1  | 1
2  | 1                            2  | 2 
3  | 2
```

Realicé la siguiente consulta.

```
$asignaciones = DB::table('asignaciones')
                    ->select('asignaciones.*')
                    ->join('ventas', 'ventas.asignacion_id', '=', 'asignaciones.id')
                    ->where('asignaciones.estado','1')
                    ->whereBetween('asignaciones.created_at', array($fecha_1, $fecha_2))
                    ->get();
```

Y me muestra esto:

Me aparece un dato duplicado, ¿existe alguna manera de poder agruparlo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para qué haces el join con ventas si no usas esa tabla para filtrar ni la muestras en los resultados?

Comment: Si la uso, para mostrar el nombre del producto que a sido asignado.

Comment: _entonces una asignación puede tener muchas ventas_... pero lo que ocurre, al menos en los datos que muestras, es lo contrario: **una venta tiene muchas asignaciones**, pues veo en la tabla ventas dos asignaciones con id=1. Me pregunto si no hay un problema de diseño en tus tablas.

Answer (score 1):

para traer las distintas asignaciones bastaría con hacer uso de [`distinct`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects).

```
$asignaciones = DB::table('asignaciones')
                ->select('asignaciones.*')
                ->distinct() // <== Con esto traes solo las asignaciones que son distintas en el corpus de datos
                ->join('ventas', 'ventas.asignacion_id', '=', 'asignaciones.id')
                ->where('asignaciones.estado','1')
                ->whereBetween('asignaciones.created_at', array($fecha_1, $fecha_2))
                ->get();
```